# Angular - export ReactiveFormsModule.withConfig

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I want to export the `ReactiveFormsModule` with the config in the `SharedModule`, but i have the below error

> Type 'ModuleWithProviders < ReactiveFormsModule > ' is missing the
> following properties from type 'Type': apply, call, bind,
> prototype, and 5 more.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule.withConfig({ warnOnNgModelWithFormControl: 'never' })
  ],
  declarations: [ ],
  exports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule.withConfig({ warnOnNgModelWithFormControl: 'never' }) // error in this line
 ],
  entryComponents: [ ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare it with this typing:

```
exports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule.withConfig({ warnOnNgModelWithFormControl: 'never' }) as unknown as Type<ModuleWithProviders<ReactiveFormsModule>>
 ],
```

Or simply:

```
exports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule.withConfig({ warnOnNgModelWithFormControl: 'never' }) as any
 ],
```

Comment: Does it really work? Typing as `any` sounds more like a hack.

Comment: It works, as Angular allows export modules. Why there is typing error exist - it's interesting... maybe need more deep research.